# The scale operation is not allowed for this subscription in this region. Try selecting different region or scale option

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am on Azure trial subscription and I try to create a QnA Maker service.  I got the error above.  I heard that the trial subscription is not allowed in West or West Central or Brazil regions.  However, I tried to create it in East or Central region and it still fails.  The detail error is below

> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment
>   operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage
>   details.","details":[{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"{\r\n \"Code\":
>   \"Unauthorized\",\r\n \"Message\": \"The scale operation is not
>   allowed for this subscription in this region. Try selecting different
>   region or scale option.\",\r\n \"Target\": null,\r\n \"Details\":
>   [\r\n {\r\n \"Message\": \"The scale operation is not allowed for this
>   subscription in this region. Try selecting different region or scale
>   option.\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Code\": \"Unauthorized\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n
>   \"ErrorEntity\": {\r\n \"ExtendedCode\": \"52020\",\r\n
>   \"MessageTemplate\": \"The scale operation is not allowed for this
>   subscription in this region. Try selecting different region or scale
>   option.\",\r\n \"Parameters\": [\r\n \"default\"\r\n ],\r\n \"Code\":
>   \"Unauthorized\",\r\n \"Message\": \"The scale operation is not
>   allowed for this subscription in this region. Try selecting different
>   region or scale option.\"\r\n }\r\n }\r\n ],\r\n \"Innererror\":
>   null\r\n}"}]}

Any insight would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the QnA maker service can only be created using a US region.

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind this error is the subscription you are using is a type that can't access the required features in the region where you are trying to deploy. For example, MSDN, Free, or Education subscriptions can show this error. Free trial or offer subscriptions are not allowed to create Azure AppService and ServerLess in West Central US and Brazil South locations, likely due to limited space. Do try other location instead.

The fix for this would be to change your subscription type or region to one that can access the required features. Also, ensure that you have required privileges on the subscription to create or update services.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, can you please accept it so that it helps others? Thanks